# Remove parent based on child value?

Tags: xslt

I want to display only those orders which dont have OrderLineSource = YTR. All other should be displayed....

My Sample XML :

```
<Orders>
<Order>
  <OrderID>34209649</OrderID>
  <OrderStatus>checkout_complete</OrderStatus>
  <Amount>32.93</Amount>
  <OrderCreation>2014-02-08T00:00:03.00</OrderCreation>
  <OrderCompletion>2014-02-08T00:00:03.00</OrderCompletion>
  <CustomerGUID>303965683</CustomerGUID>
  <CSMPurchaserGUID>0</CSMPurchaserGUID>
  <Brand>TRFE</Brand>
  <SourceECommerceSystem>Framework</SourceECommerceSystem>
  <Currency>GBP</Currency>
  <OrderChannel>Online</OrderChannel>
  <TransactionSummary>
     <TransactionID>2407065</TransactionID>
     <MerchantReference>TEdV-5648-34209649</MerchantReference>
     <CardCategory>Personal</CardCategory>
     <CardScheme>VISA Debit</CardScheme>
     <CardCountry>gbr</CardCountry>
     <CardIssuer>sdfsdf sdf Bank asdf</CardIssuer>
     <CardStartDate>0/0</CardStartDate>
     <CardExpiryDate>2016/08</CardExpiryDate>
     <Amount>32.93</Amount>
     <Currency>GBP</Currency>
     <CardPAN>************4585</CardPAN>
     <Created>2014-02-07T23:56:48</Created>
     <Updated>2014-02-08T00:00:03</Updated>
     <ResponseStatusCode>1</ResponseStatusCode>
     <ResponseStatusReason>FULFILLED OK</ResponseStatusReason>
     <HostedPageIdentifier>dsfasdf-ee85-4afa-bb6a-0afc6dc99896</HostedPageIdentifier>
     <HostedPageURL>https://hps.datacash.com/hps/</HostedPageURL>
     <PaymentStatus>Paid</PaymentStatus>
     <PaymentType>Debit Card</PaymentType>
     <NameOnCard>Miss L J adsf</NameOnCard>
     <DataCashRef>56456456454</DataCashRef>
     <MerchantID>545646</MerchantID>
     <ThreeDCard>1</ThreeDCard>
     <ThreeDRequested>1</ThreeDRequested>
     <IPAddress>127.89.560.1</IPAddress>
  </TransactionSummary>
  <OrderLine>
     <OrderLineID>84598837</OrderLineID>
     <OrderID>34209649</OrderID>
     <OrderLineLabel>GAREGSBV</OrderLineLabel>
     <OrderLineSource>GHR</OrderLineSource>
     <Quantity>1</Quantity>
     <UnitPrice>32.93</UnitPrice>
     <Total>32.93</Total>
     <SKUCode>P0032</SKUCode>
     <Title>Miss.</Title>
     <FirstName>ertwer</FirstName>
     <FamilyName>sdaf</FamilyName>
     <DateOfBirth>1984-05-30</DateOfBirth>
     <Email>sdfasdfa@hotmail.com</Email>
     <Mobile>645646454</Mobile>
     <PostChannel>0</PostChannel>
     <TelephoneChannel>0</TelephoneChannel>
     <EmailChannel>0</EmailChannel>
     <TextAndOtherChannel>0</TextAndOtherChannel>
     <BuildingNumber>27</BuildingNumber>
     <AddressLine1>27</AddressLine1>
     <AddressLine2>dsfasdf Road</AddressLine2>
     <Town>London</Town>
     <Country>sdfasdf er</Country>
     <Postcode>KL7 2NS</Postcode>
     <AddressValidated>1</AddressValidated>
     <HKPolicy>
        <PolicyNum>PP01754397</PolicyNum>
        <ProductDescription>sadfsadfasdfgasdg</ProductDescription>
        <CoverTypeDesc>Individual</CoverTypeDesc>
        <SingleParentFamilyFlag>0</SingleParentFamilyFlag>
        <PolicyTypeRefID>S</PolicyTypeRefID>
        <PolicyTypeDesc>Sinasdfnce</PolicyTypeDesc>
        <TierDesc>Classic</TierDesc>
        <DestinationDesc>Worldwide including USA, Canada, Caribbean</DestinationDesc>
        <TotalTravellers>1</TotalTravellers>
        <NumOfAdults>1</NumOfAdults>
        <NumOfUnder18>0</NumOfUnder18>
        <PolicyStartDate>2014-02-08</PolicyStartDate>
        <PolicyEndDate>2014-02-12</PolicyEndDate>
        <BaseCost>32.93</BaseCost>
        <Commission>11.18</Commission>
        <UpsoldInd>0</UpsoldInd>
        <TierRefID>C</TierRefID>
        <DestinationRefID>W2</DestinationRefID>
        <CoverTypeRefID>I</CoverTypeRefID>
        <AONToPostPolicy>yes</AONToPostPolicy>
        <SalesChannel>0011002</SalesChannel>
        <WhereYouHeardOfUs>Press advertising</WhereYouHeardOfUs>
        <TIPOLTraveller>
           <TravellerUUID>1864-1</TravellerUUID>
           <PolicyNum>PI0e31754397</PolicyNum>
           <Title>Miss</Title>
           <FirstName>sdfsf</FirstName>
           <FamilyName>sdfsdf</FamilyName>
           <DateOfBirth>1984-05-30</DateOfBirth>
           <AgeBand>1864</AgeBand>
           <DependentFlag>0</DependentFlag>
        </TIPOLTraveller>
     </TIPOLPolicy>
  </OrderLine>
  <OrderCustomerDetails>
     <Title nil="true" />
     <FirstName nil="true" />
     <SecondName nil="true" />
     <FamilyName nil="true" />
     <DateOfBirth nil="true" />
     <Email nil="true" />
     <Telephone nil="true" />
     <Mobile nil="true" />
     <Gender nil="true" />
     <PostChannel nil="true" />
     <TelephoneChannel nil="true" />
     <EmailChannel nil="true" />
     <TextAndOtherChannel nil="true" />
     <BuildingNumber>27</BuildingNumber>
     <AddressLine1>27</AddressLine1>
     <AddressLine2>asdfa Road</AddressLine2>
     <Town>asdfasdf</Town>
     <Country>United dsf</Country>
     <Postcode>KH9 2NS</Postcode>
     <AddressValidated>1</AddressValidated>
  </OrderCustomerDetails>
</Order>
<Order>
  <OrderID>34209674</OrderID>
  <OrderStatus>checkout_complete</OrderStatus>
  <Amount>11.13</Amount>
  <OrderCreation>2014-02-08T00:08:40.00</OrderCreation>
  <OrderCompletion>2014-02-08T00:08:40.00</OrderCompletion>
  <CustomerGUID>303965688</CustomerGUID>
  <CSMPurchaserGUID>0</CSMPurchaserGUID>
  <Brand>TRFDS</Brand>
  <SourceECommerceSystem>Framework</SourceECommerceSystem>
  <Currency>GBP</Currency>
  <OrderChannel>Online</OrderChannel>
  <TransactionSummary>
     <TransactionID>8115032</TransactionID>
     <MerchantReference>JHF-0800-34209674</MerchantReference>
     <CardCategory>Personal</CardCategory>
     <CardScheme>VISA Debit</CardScheme>
     <CardCountry>gbr</CardCountry>
     <CardIssuer>Unknown</CardIssuer>
     <CardStartDate>0/0</CardStartDate>
     <CardExpiryDate>2016/09</CardExpiryDate>
     <Amount>11.13</Amount>
     <Currency>GBP</Currency>
     <CardPAN>************4849</CardPAN>
     <Created>2014-02-08T00:08:00</Created>
     <Updated>2014-02-08T00:08:40</Updated>
     <ResponseStatusCode>1</ResponseStatusCode>
     <ResponseStatusReason>FULFILLED OK</ResponseStatusReason>
     <HostedPageIdentifier>f3306487-d6ea-4200-9eea-99b1d6832a2e</HostedPageIdentifier>
     <HostedPageURL>https://hps.dat.com/hps/</HostedPageURL>
     <PaymentStatus>Paid</PaymentStatus>
     <PaymentType>Debit Card</PaymentType>
     <NameOnCard>Miss Jor </NameOnCard>
     <DataCashRef>380010093738013</DataCashRef>
     <MerchantID>21877049</MerchantID>
     <ThreeDCard>1</ThreeDCard>
     <ThreeDRequested>1</ThreeDRequested>
     <IPAddress>86..25640.99</IPAddress>
  </TransactionSummary>
  <OrderLine>
     <OrderLineID>84598874</OrderLineID>
     <OrderID>34209674</OrderID>
     <OrderLineLabel>3-1008617753325</OrderLineLabel>
     <OrderLineSource>YTR</OrderLineSource>
     <Quantity>1</Quantity>
     <UnitPrice>11.13</UnitPrice>
     <Total>11.13</Total>
     <Title>Miss.</Title>
     <FirstName>Jordan</FirstName>
     <SecondName>oirut</SecondName>
     <FamilyName>dfgsdfgs</FamilyName>
     <Email>dfgsdfg@hotmail.com</Email>
     <Mobile>654756464</Mobile>
     <PostChannel>0</PostChannel>
     <TelephoneChannel>0</TelephoneChannel>
     <EmailChannel>0</EmailChannel>
     <TextAndOtherChannel>0</TextAndOtherChannel>
     <BuildingNumber>12</BuildingNumber>
     <AddressLine1>12</AddressLine1>
     <AddressLine2>sfgsdfg End Gardens</AddressLine2>
     <Town>HEMEL sfgaefa</Town>
     <Country>adf dgfsdfg</Country>
     <Postcode>HP1 1SN</Postcode>
     <OrderLineDetail>
        <NameValuePair>
           <Name>dfgsdfg</Name>
           <Value>628</Value>
        </NameValuePair>
        <NameValuePair>
           <Name>NameOnCard</Name>
           <Value>adsfgasdgf Piper</Value>
        </NameValuePair>
        <NameValuePair>
           <Name>DateOnCard</Name>
           <Value>2014-02-05</Value>
        </NameValuePair>
        <NameValuePair>
           <Name>CustomsOrSurcharge</Name>
           <Value>CUSTOMS CHARGE TO PAY</Value>
        </NameValuePair>
     </OrderLineDetail>
  </OrderLine>
  <OrderCustomerDetails>
     <Title>Miss.</Title>
     <FirstName>Jordan</FirstName>
     <SecondName>asdgfasdgf</SecondName>
     <FamilyName nil="true" />
     <DateOfBirth />
     <Email>adfadf@hotmail.com</Email>
     <Telephone />
     <Mobile>adfasdf</Mobile>
     <Gender nil="true" />
     <PostChannel nil="true" />
     <TelephoneChannel nil="true" />
     <EmailChannel nil="true" />
     <TextAndOtherChannel nil="true" />
     <BuildingNumber>12</BuildingNumber>
     <AddressLine1>12</AddressLine1>
     <AddressLine2>adfasdf End Gardens</AddressLine2>
     <Town>adsfasdf HEMPSTEAD</Town>
     <Country>United asdfasdf</Country>
     <Postcode>asd 1SN</Postcode>
  </OrderCustomerDetails>
</Order>
</Orders>
```

I tried using XSLT :

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<!-- Orders -->
<xsl:template match="/*">
 <xsl:element name="Orders">
   <xsl:apply-templates select="./Order" /> 
 </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<!-- Orders > Order -->
<xsl:template match="/Order">
  <xsl:variable name="IsValid">
  <xsl:call-template name="HasOrIsValidPOLine" />
</xsl:variable>
 <xsl:if test="$IsValid='VALID'"> <!-- only display the order if there's a valid line under it-->
  <xsl:element name="Order">
    <xsl:apply-templates select=".//VORNR" />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
 <!-- Part Order List > Part Order > Operational BO Number -->
 <xsl:template match="//VORNR">
 <xsl:element name="./Order">
 <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="text()"/>
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="HasOrIsValidPOLine">
 <xsl:choose>
   <xsl:when test="./OrderLineSource/text() != 'YTR'">VALID</xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>INVALID</xsl:otherwise>
 </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
 <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
 </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Can you provide me the solution or let me know where I am going wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, your sample XML is not well-formed: It contains a closing `</TIPOLPolicy>` tag that doesn't match the starting `<HKPolicy>` tag. Change that to `</HKPolicy>` first.

After that, the following XSLT 1.0 does what you want:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

    <!-- Identity transform -->
    <!-- Default priority 0 for root node and -0.5 for the rest -->
    <xsl:template match="/ | node() | @*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- Do nothing for Order elements whose OrderLine/OrderLineSource equals 'YTR' -->
    <!-- Default priority 0.5 -->
    <xsl:template match="Order[OrderLine/OrderLineSource = 'YTR']"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It makes use of the identity transform and different default priorities: The identity transform with a lower default priority copies the input to the output unless another template with a higher priority exists for a given input match. This is the case for Order elements whose `OrderLine/OrderLineSource` descendant contains the text value 'YTR'. Due to its higher default priority, the more specific template takes precedence over the identity transform. Since the template doesn't produce any output, any matching `Order` elements are removed from the output.

Answer (score 0):

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Order[OrderLine/OrderLineSource[string() = 'YTR']]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```